# I am having trouble Moqing UoW and my Repo

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I am trying to set up Moq for Unit Testing for the first time. I have already tested the Unit of Work and Repository against a real database, I can Insert, Remove, Find by Id, etc. (I am using TPH as I have Residential Customers as well as Business Customers.) This Test with Moq works:

```
const int expectedId = 1;
ResidentialCustomer expected = new ResidentialCustomer("Bob", "Smith")
{
    Id = expectedId,
    AccountNumber = 1
};

IQueryable<ResidentialCustomer> data = new List<ResidentialCustomer>
{
    expected,
    new ResidentialCustomer("Nancy", "Smith") {Id = 2, AccountNumber = 2},
    new ResidentialCustomer("John", "Doe") {Id = 3, AccountNumber = 3},
    new ResidentialCustomer("Jane", "Doe") {Id = 4, AccountNumber = 4}
}.AsQueryable();

var dbSetMock = new Mock<IDbSet<Customer>>();
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

var customDbContextMock = new Mock<RealContext>();
customDbContextMock
    .Setup(x => x.Customers)
    .Returns(dbSetMock.Object);

var actual = (ResidentialCustomer) customDbContextMock.Object.Customers.First();

Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
Assert.AreEqual(expected.Id, actual.Id);
Assert.AreEqual(expected.FirstName, actual.FirstName);
```

This Test does not **(Update)**: 'actual' is null and the first Assert fails.

```
const int expectedId = 1;
ResidentialCustomer expected = new ResidentialCustomer("Bob", "Smith")
{
    Id = expectedId,
    AccountNumber = 1
};

IQueryable<ResidentialCustomer> data = new List<ResidentialCustomer>
{
    expected,
    new ResidentialCustomer("Nancy", "Smith") {Id = 2, AccountNumber = 2},
    new ResidentialCustomer("John", "Doe") {Id = 3, AccountNumber = 3},
    new ResidentialCustomer("Jane", "Doe") {Id = 4, AccountNumber = 4}
}.AsQueryable();

var dbSetMock = new Mock<IDbSet<Customer>>();
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

var customDbContextMock = new Mock<RealContext>();
customDbContextMock
    .Setup(x => x.Customers)
    .Returns(dbSetMock.Object);

var uow = new UnitOfWork(customDbContextMock.Object);
var repo = uow.CustomerRepository;

var actual = (ResidentialCustomer) repo.GetAllCustomers().First();

Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
Assert.AreEqual(expected.Id, actual.Id);
Assert.AreEqual(expected.FirstName, actual.FirstName);
```

Thank you in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? Doesn't compile? Test fails? Throws an exception?

Comment: @James sorry I wasn't clear. Doesn't work means 'actual' is null and the first Assert fails.

Comment: you have also to mock the unitOfWork .setup(u=> u,CustomerRepository).Return(dbSetMock) ?  and also you have to mock GetAllCustomers();